# How to get a lookup through multiple tables

Tags: ms-access

I got three tables that are dependent 1t:N after each other.

```
foo --> fooBar --> fooBarBaz
    1:n        1:n
----------------------------
fooID  | barID   |  BazID  
Name   | Name    |  
       | fooID   |  barID
```

I can easily create those with the Lookup & Relationship dialog. In `fooBar` there is still the `fooID`, which is displayed with the `foo.Name`.

Is there now a possibility to display the `foo.Name`and the `fooBar.Name` in the `fooBarBaz` table ?

Expressions do not allow me to use DLookup, so how can I display that nicely?

Comment: Use a _query_. Tasks like this is exactly what they are for.

Comment: as Gustav said, queries are designed for this purpose exactly. Unless you need the values inserted/duplicated across multiple tables. However i would not recommend this and would be a different issue entirely

Comment: @Gustav Can I insert into a query? Or do I then  also need to create a form?

Comment: Yes, though often read-only queries are widely used. And a form is typically bound to a query. Find a guide for "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar.